# SQL Query (Transpose?)

Tags: sql

I made this query to select values from a DB.

```
SELECT
SAMPLE_TIME, ENTITY, STAT_GROUP, STAT_ID, STAT_NAME, CONVERT(decimal(16,2), STAT_VALUE/100.0) AS PERCENTAGE
FROM
VPXV_HIST_STAT_YEARLY WHERE ENTITY LIKE 'vm-1783'
AND SAMPLE_TIME > '2017-10-01'
AND SAMPLE_TIME < '2017-12-31'
AND ((STAT_GROUP = 'CPU' OR STAT_GROUP = 'MEM'))
AND STAT_NAME = 'USAGE'
ORDER by SAMPLE_TIME,STAT_GROUP ASC
```

This is the output:

| Data       | Entity  | Stat_Group | Stat_ID | Stat_Name | Percentage |
|------------|---------|------------|---------|-----------|------------|
| 2017-10-02 | vm-1783 | cpu        | 2       | usage     | 12.04      |
| 2017-10-02 | vm-1783 | mem        | 24      | usage     | 7.21       |
| 2017-10-03 | vm-1783 | cpu        | 2       | usage     | 4.89       |
| 2017-10-03 | vm-1783 | mem        | 24      | usage     | 2.69       |

But i would like to get this kind of output:
| Data          | CPU       | MEM   |
|------------   |-------    |------ |
| 2017-10-02    | 12.04     | 7.21  |
| 2017-10-03    | 4.89      | 2.69  |

Tried pivoitng but maybe i made some mistake.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SAMPLE_TIME,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STAT_GROUP = 'MEM'
                THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2), STAT_VALUE / 100.0) 
           END) as CPU,
       MAX(CASE WHEN STAT_GROUP = 'MEM'
                THEN CONVERT(decimal(16,2), STAT_VALUE / 100.0) 
           END) as CPU,
FROM VPXV_HIST_STAT_YEARLY
WHERE ENTITY LIKE 'vm-1783' AND
      SAMPLE_TIME > '2017-10-01' AND
      SAMPLE_TIME < '2017-12-31' AND
      STAT_GROUP IN ('CPU', 'MEM') AND
      STAT_NAME = 'USAGE'
GROUP BY SAMPLE_TIME
ORDER by SAMPLE_TIME;
```

Comment: IT WORKED!
+-------------------------+-------+-------+

| 2017-10-02 00:00:00.000 | 12.04 | 7.21  |

+-------------------------+-------+-------+

| 2017-10-03 00:00:00.000 | 4.89  | 2.69  |

+-------------------------+-------+-------+

| 2017-10-04 00:00:00.000 | 13.70 | 18.33 |

+-------------------------+-------+-------+

| 2017-10-05 00:00:00.000 | 21.80 | 30.82 |

+-------------------------+-------+-------+

| 2017-10-06 00:00:00.000 | 11.67 | 16.33 |

+-------------------------+-------+-------+